# order by associated model position

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a set of questions specific to a user, now I want to order them by a position given in an associated model.

The associated model is called `questions_postions` and have a `position` integer column. Now the questions may be there, or it may be nil.

I've tried:

```
 employee.questions.order(questions.positions.position or 0).each do |q|
```

but that returns:

```
undefined local variable or method `questions_positions'
```

the associations are setup:

Question:

```
has_many :questions_positions
```

QuestionsPosition:

```
class QuestionsPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :ownerable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
employee.questions.joins(:positions).order('positions.position DESC')
```

Comment: Could you describe a little what are you trying to do here?